# Use of TRUE:FALSE in eval javascript returns the statement being evaluated

Tags: eval, imacros

I have gotten this far into a imacros code to compare IP's with intention that `TRUE` is returned when the `"PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}"` gets to a working proxy at that port. Being new at iMacros and know even less of javascript, I managed with variables and extractions to get this far  [edited to include the whole code]

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379 RECORDER=FX
SET !ENCRYPTION NO    
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'clear cookies and cache:
CLEAR
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !DATASOURCE C:\MyiMacros\DATAinputs\VerifyTheseProxies.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET NewTestProxy {{!COL1}}:{{!COL2}}
PROMPT  {{NewTestProxy}}
PROXY ADDRESS={{NewTestProxy}}
URL GOTO=geoiptool.com
WAIT SECONDS=2
 ' ooppss  proxy doesn't work
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:ProxyDetail EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
SET ProxyFails {{!EXTRACT}}
PROMPT {{ProxyFails}}<SP>{{!COL1}}:{{!COL2}}
SET YesPrxyFail (if('{{NewTestProxy}}'.equals('{{ProxyFails}}'))?"TRUE":"FALSE");
PROMPT {{YesPrxyFail}}
```

and I was expecting `TRUE` from when NewTestProxy is exactly same as ProxyFails, but instead I get the whole complet expression returned as though was not being seen as javascript ...

```
(if('{{NewTestProxy}}'.equals('{{ProxyFails}}'))?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

getting that type of result

using

```
SET YesPrxyFail EVAL(('{{NewTestProxy
```

and I tried the suggested

```
SET YesPrxyFail (if('{{NewTestProxy
```

also I tried the suggested

```
SET YesPrxyFail eval(if('{{NewTestProxy
```

I felt I was following all the sample pieces I dug up here and on the imacros site, as well as others . I missed something 'small' and I dont know what it is. Help will be appreciated!

I have a solution, but not 100% comfortable. Both of these return "TRUE", but use two different comparaters

```
SET YesPrxyFail EVAL("var s = \"{{ProxyFails}}\"===\"{{NewTestProxy}}\"; s;")
SET YesPrxyFail EVAL("var s = \"{{ProxyFails}}\"==\"{{NewTestProxy}}\"; s;")
```

given that the source of the two variables is a proxy address, AND the two variables received could (theory?) be objects from different sources, then strictly they can not be the same. Found this as a reference but I dont know how to check for type or if in fact the variables I am testing are objects or not ..

:https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

As a heads up there is error if the iMacros 'EVAL' is removed: it is not the javascript eval

Comment: Not sure of my interpretation of the sites rules are correct ... should the new question about my possible solution be in a new thread ???

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should not use EVAL in this manner, rather you should use if clause with ternary operator (i.e. ? : ), like following -

if('{{NewTestProxy}}'.equals('{{ProxyFails}}'))?"TRUE":"FALSE";

and then use the result of this statement in eval method, as eval() method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

You should use following code, it will help you :

eval(if('{{NewTestProxy}}'.equals('{{ProxyFails}}'))?"TRUE":"FALSE");

Please revert in case of any confusion.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and both had the same outcome as mine. TY for input though!

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found

> `SET YesPrxyFail EVAL("var s = \"{{ProxyFails}}\"==\"{{NewTestProxy}}\"; s;")`

is perfectly alright. Those are simply strings. iMacros read a text string from the csv file (NewTestProxy), extracted a text from the web page (ProxyFails) and EVAL is comparing the two strings. If they are identical, you get "true" (also as string!).